# Publish Message from Confluent Control Center with Header

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-dotnet, confluent-control-center

I'm trying to publish a message on a Kafka topic from the control center for initial testing.  I need to include a header in the message. Can this be done from the control center?

[image]

Comment: It does not appear that is possible, no. Ideally, you'd use the `kafka-console-producer` or `kcat` for testing, not a UI tool